# Command "return" in Tcl. Can it return a variable and be printed?

Tags: tcl

Is "return" capable of printing a variable?

For illustrating the use of "uplevel" in Tcl8.6 I elaborated following script for helping me to understand the use of "uplevel".

```
    set a goodbye

proc test {} {
    set a hello
    uplevel #0 {return $a}
}

test
```

The example is base on this script I found at wiki.tcl.tk:

```
set x goodbye

apply {{} {
        set x hello 
        uplevel {return $x}
}}
```

But when i execute them none prints $x.

Thanks

Comment: No. `return` won't print the value, unless you explicitly print or override the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` command *returns* the value. It leaves printing to `puts` or to the caller. Or you can use a leave trace on the procedure's execution to do it:

```
proc test {args} {
    return "abc"
}
trace add execution test leave {apply {{cmd code result op} {
    puts "the result was '$result'"
}}}
test 123
#>>> the result was 'abc'
#abc
```

Also, don't do `uplevel return`. The results will be confusing to you.